# How to save and restore positions of detached windows which are placed on a secondary display?

Tags: windows, eclipse-rcp

One set of users are using my RCP application on a workstation with 2 displays. The second display is a small USB device which they can hold in their hand as they move around. A couple of Views are pulled from the standard perspective and moved to the USB display. The positions of all windows are saved and restored correctly when the application is closed and restarted.

The problems begin when one of the displays is removed. (The USB display seems to be a bit 'wobbly' and resets itself) The views on that display get moved to the other display and the positions are not restored when the display is reactivated. I realise that this is all very sensible but I would like to be able to react to the situation and provide a way to restore the positions quickly.

One idea is to provide a perspective for 2-display mode but I haven't seen a way to define perspectives which use detached views.

Another is to define an action which saves the position of all detached Views and another action to restore these views. How can I query detached Views and their positions?

My last idea builds on the previous one. The positions are saved and a task scans the currently attached displays. When a display is removed and reattached this is detected and the view positions are restored.

Any other ideas? Detaching views seemed like a good idea but it is beginning to cause serious frustration.

**UPDATE**

I tried to catch the move and resize events of my views but no events are raised when a display is removed and Windows repositions the windows. (Idea from http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2010/06/23/tip-how-to-detect-that-a-view-was-detached/)

```
@Override
public final void createPartControl(Composite parent)
{
    this.parent = parent;
    parent.addControlListener(new ControlAdapter() { 
        @Override 
        public void controlResized(ControlEvent e) { 
            updateDetached(); 
        } 

        @Override
        public void controlMoved(ControlEvent e)
        {
            updateDetached();
        }
    }); 

    onCreatePartControl(parent);
    updateDetached(); 
}

private void updateDetached()
{
    isDetached = parent.getShell().getText().length() == 0;
    if(isDetached)
    {
        System.out.println(parent.getShell().getDisplay().getBounds());
        System.out.println(parent.getShell().getBounds());
    }
}
```